# Simple python regex groups can't parse date

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x, regex-group

I'm trying to parse dates with regex, using groups, but python is returning empty lists.  I'm not doing anything fancy, just 12/25/10 sort of stuff.  I want it to reject 12/25-10 though.

```
date = re.compile("\d{1,2}([/.-])\d{1,2}\1\d{2}")
```

I've tried online regex libraries, but their solutions don't seem to run either.  Any ideas?

Sample input: "Hello today is 10/18/10, and the time is 10:50am"
Hopeful output: "10/18/10"

I'm running Python 2.5.

Comment: Are you trying to find dates in a longer string, or are you trying to confirm that a given string is a date?

Comment: I'm trying to find 1+ dates in a longer string, which will be filled with other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a raw string:

```
date = re.compile(r"\d{1,2}([/.-])\d{1,2}\1\d{2}")
```

Otherwise, the `\1` in the string literal is interpreted as the character 1 (Start of Heading).

EDIT: To add groups for the date components, use:

```
re.compile(r"(\d{1,2})([/.-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2})")
```

Comment: when I try this, all it returns is ['/']

Comment: @ehfeng, that's because you don't have groups for the digits.

Comment: I don't understand - should I add parenthesis around all of the digits as well?  I would like the regex to return "12/25/10", if possible.

Comment: @ehfeng: what are you doing with your compeiled regex: search? match? findall? finditer? Also show us some sample input.

Answer (score 5):

You should use Python's builtin [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Answer (score 2):

No doubt overkill, but the "parsedatetime" library has been working for me: http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/

It does use regexes internally, but does a lot more than parse MM/DD/YY formats.